# How to limit a user to one visit on a single page?

Tags: php, redirect

Hello Guys i hate asking stupid questions here so i hope this isn't, How would i go about limiting someone to a download page of mine? so if they try to visit that page again  (more then once) to download something it will just redirect or preferably change the download links to `link 2` then `Link 3` and is it possible to do without a database?

Eg:

1. First Visit - main link
2. Second Visit- link 2
3. third Visit- link 3
4. 4 and up Visit no link and redirect

Maybe with cookies? i really i have no idea how to do it and i have Googled it but my wording must not be there...

Is there a name for this or a script?

Thanks for your time Guys.

Comment: have you tried cookies?

Comment: Do NOT use cookies. The user can delete any cookies, rendering your "protection" useless.

Comment: Without a DB, it might be hard to be foolproof, but `$_SESSION` vars could be your best bet.

Comment: @DannyBeckett, Instead of saying "do not use cookies", I suggest "do not **only** use cookies".  And, no matter what, there is no fool-proof way unless the link can only be visited once at all.

Comment: It doesn't have to be fool proof, just to stop your average user? so even if the cookies can be bypass and even if they can delete them that's good enough so with cookies how would i go about it? im looking for a quick temp fix while i learn about databases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A.**
The best method to achieve the desired goal is `database`. Create a database table that contains two columns :

```
(1)Page Visitors IP
(2)The Last Download link used by the visitor to download
 file(contents) from your website.
```

**B.**
You can too achieve your goal with the  help of  [COOKIE](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php).

```
setcookie("Visitor IP", "Download Link used by the Visitor", $expire);
```

Everytime, visitors visit your website, fetch the visitor IP and check whether `$_COOKIE["Visitor IP"]` is set or not, if its set, then update the existing Cookie else create the new one.

However, using Cookie is  not a convenient way, as there might be a case where

```
  Browser does NOT Support Cookies.
  Client  alter the Cookies value and use the previous link for download.
```

So,  most simplest and elegant way to do it is, using  `Database`.

**UPD:**
**How easy is it to code/setup a database?**

Setting up/Connecting to a database in php is pretty easy.
Refer the following  [LINK](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)

Coding is pretty easy as well.

-Whenever the  visitor click on the download link, fetch Visitors IP ($fetched_IP) by either POST or GET method. Also fetch the Link ($URL) visitor has clicked.

-`Query the database` [eg: [Select](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp) DB_IP,LASTLINK from database WHERE DB_IP=$fetched_IP.....]

-If [RowCount](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php)>0, then IP`($fetched_IP`) exists in database. Check the Last Link visited by the `$fetched_IP`.

-If `LASTLINK!=$URL`, then allow him download the content from `$URL`.[Update](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp) the LAST_LINK column in database table by `$URL`.

-If rowcount==0,(`New User`) [Insert](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp) a row that contains DB_IP=$fetched_IP(Visitor IP) and LAST_LINK=$URL.

Comment: @user1871802:Check my Update (UPD)

Answer (score 0):

An easy was is to use a hash table (associative array).  When they satisfy the criteria to access the file, add an entry to the hash table using the the unique url as the key and the document path as the value.  Save it to the session.  When they access the url the page checks to see if the url is in the hash table.  If it is, remove the url from the hash table and stream the file.  If you wanted to allow multiple uses, you could store a countdown variable along with the url, that will decrement with every access and only delete the url from the hash table when the count is zero.